# How can I get all my email messages using OpenPop and also show progress of messages retrieving on a progressBar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a link for the OpenPop what I'm using in my project:

[OpenPop](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/)

This is a page with examples:

[Example](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleFetchAllMessages.php)

And this is my code. In form1 designer I added a progressBar.

What I want to do is to get all the messages I have on my server and show in a progressBar the progress of the messages retrieving.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pop3_Emails
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
            PopClient.Connect("mail.bezeqint.net", 110, false);
            PopClient.Authenticate("meemail", "password",
                OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
            int messageCount = PopClient.GetMessageCount();
            List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
            }

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0,PopClient.GetMessageCount().ToString());
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is that i'm getting two errors on the line:

```
allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
```

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Message)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OpenPop.Mime.Message' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Message'

The second problem is how to report to the progressBar the progress ? Somehow from inside the FOR loop.

Comment: Qualify message with a namespace in your declaration of `List<Message>` (or use using) to disambiguate OpenPops  message object from .Nets `System.Windows.Forms.Message`

Comment: As AlexK is saying, List<Message> is not working, because it will resolve to List<System.Windows.Forms.Message>. You have to write List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> and then you can fill in your messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, first question is solved by AlexK.

Second question can by solved by setting:

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

and in your for loop you can calculate and report progress by:

```
int nProgress = (messageCount - i) * 100 / messageCount;
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, nProgress);
```

So now, you can show your progress:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int nProgress = (int)e.UserState;
    label1.Text = nProgress.ToString();
    progressBar1.Value = nProgress;
}
```

But what i also see is, that you are adding all downloaded messages to local variable `List<Message> allMessages`. So they get lost when downloading has finished. May be you should move it into the class...